# How to access Django Rest Api from Acrobat PDF JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, django, rest, pdf, acrobat

I have an API created using Django Rest.  
The url is live and running on a server that I have access to.
When the url is hit

```
https://myurl.com/api/test?format=json
```

This is returned:

```
{"currentNumber":51,"iterativeField":"51","maxNumberOfDigitsInNum":2}
```

I need to access this data through an Acrobat PDF button.  
I'm using Acrobat Pro.  In the pdf I add a button.  
The button trigger is 'Mouse Up'.  
The Action is 'Run a JavaScript'.

The JavaScript itself is:

```
var tempVar = getURL("https://myurl.com/api/test?format=json", "_blank", "GET");
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
NotAllowedError: Security settings prevent access to this property or method.
Doc.getURL:1:Field Button1:Mouse Up
```

I checked the security on the PDF and there is 'no security'.  Everything is allowed.
I am not sure how to proceed.  Where do I need to set up this security?

Comment: What are the security settings in the JavaScript tab of the Preferences of Acrobat? The Security settings concerned are not tied to the document, but to the application. Also, you may have to properly URLencode the URL, meaning that, for example, the space character is replaces with its URL entity, etc..

Comment: There is no security active for Acrobat.  Also there is no security on the api url.

Comment: I am talking of the JavaScript Security settings in the JavaScript Preferences tab.

Comment: In Acrobat Pro> Preferences> JavaScript: 'Enable Acrobat JavaScript' is checked.  'Enable menu items JavaScript execution privileges' is not checked.  'Enable global object security policy' is not checked.

Comment: Thanks. You might to check the Enable menu items JavaScript execution privileges (with that settings, you have the most functional settings for Acrobat JavaScript). One more thing you may try is to create a privileged function to get the tempVar value; see Acrobat JavaScript documentation for how to set up a privileged function.

Comment: After some research I believe this problem has little to do with security and more to do with the inability of Acrobat PDF to connect to a Rest API.  There is a way to access data with a SOAP connection but not REST.  Currently I'm looking into using Net.http.request().  This will give me more access to different networking protocols where I may be able to retrieve my REST data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acrobat does have JavaScript but it's own version, 'Acrobat JavaScript'; and it has limitations.  It does not have all the functionality as HTML JavaScript.  Attempting to access a url outside of the pdf does not work using Acrobat JavaScript.  The work around was to pull the data from the API using urllib, then create another pdf and squish the two PDFs together.  I was able to do this using Python/Django.